# How to remove exception ????? android.view.inflateException:Binary XML file line#7 : error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android

- In my code in fragment class, I have implemented everything.. but while inflating it from xml, fiving inflateexceptiom...

  - Fragment Class:

    ```
    package com.nyural.calendar;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Currency;
    import java.util.Locale;

    import com.nyurals.school.R;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.GestureDetector;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewConfiguration;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
    import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.GridView;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;



    public class CalendarWeeklyView extends Fragment {

        private GridView calendarGrid;
        private ViewSwitcher calendarSwitcher;

        private Calendar weekCalendar;
        private Locale locale;
        private CalendarAdapterWeekly calendarAdapterWeekly;
        private TextView currentWeek;
        private GestureDetector swipeDetector;
        private RelativeLayout calendarLayoutWeekly;

        public CalendarWeeklyView() {

            try {

                weekCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                locale = Locale.getDefault();
            } catch(Exception ex) {

            }

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            try {
                calendarLayoutWeekly  = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.calender_weekly,null);
                GridView calendarDayGridWeekly = (GridView) calendarLayoutWeekly.findViewById(R.id.calendar_days_grid_weekly);
                swipeDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity(),new SwipeGesture(getActivity()));
                calendarGrid = (GridView) calendarLayoutWeekly.findViewById(R.id.calendar_grid_weekly);
                calendarSwitcher = (ViewSwitcher) calendarLayoutWeekly.findViewById(R.id.calendar_switcher_weekly);

                currentWeek = (TextView) calendarLayoutWeekly.findViewById(R.id.currentWeekDateWithMonth);

                calendarAdapterWeekly = new CalendarAdapterWeekly(getActivity());

                calendarGrid.setAdapter(calendarAdapterWeekly);

                updateCurrentWeek();
                calendarDayGridWeekly.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity(),R.layout.calendar_item_week,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weekly_days_array)));
                calendarGrid.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {



                        return swipeDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    }
                });
                //return calendarLayoutWeekly;
            } catch(Exception ex) {

            }
            return calendarLayoutWeekly;

        }

        private void updateCurrentWeek() {
            try {

                //calendarAdapterWeekly.refreshDays();
                currentWeek.setText(String.format(locale, "%tm" , weekCalendar) + "/" + weekCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
                currentWeek.append("-" + String.format(locale, "%tm", weekCalendar) + "/" + weekCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE + 7));
            } catch(Exception ex) {

            }

        }
        private void onPreviousWeek() {

            calendarSwitcher.setInAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.in_from_left);
            calendarSwitcher.setOutAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.out_to_right);
            calendarSwitcher.showPrevious();
            if (weekCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.JANUARY) {
                weekCalendar.set((weekCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1), Calendar.DECEMBER, 1);
            } else {
                weekCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, weekCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)-1);
                //weekCalendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, weekCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH) - 7);

            }
            updateCurrentWeek();



        }

        private void onNextWeek() {
            calendarSwitcher.setInAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.in_from_right);
            calendarSwitcher.setOutAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.out_to_left);
            calendarSwitcher.showNext();
            if(weekCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.DECEMBER){
                weekCalendar.set((weekCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1),Calendar.JANUARY,1);
            } else {
                weekCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH , weekCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
                //weekCalendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, weekCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH) + 7);

            }
            updateCurrentWeek();

        }

        private final class SwipeGesture extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

            private final int swipeMinDistance;
            private final int swipeThresholdVelocity;


            public SwipeGesture(Context context) {

                final ViewConfiguration viewConfig = ViewConfiguration.get(context);
                swipeMinDistance = viewConfig.getScaledTouchSlop();
                swipeThresholdVelocity = viewConfig.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity();

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                    float velocityY) {

                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > swipeMinDistance && Math.abs(velocityX) > swipeThresholdVelocity) {
                    onNextWeek();
                } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > swipeMinDistance && Math.abs(velocityX) > swipeThresholdVelocity) {
                    onPreviousWeek();
                }
                return false;
            }



        }


    }
    ```

    - Now I am using this class in actvity_timetable.xml as,

    ```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentForTimeTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.nyural.calendar.CalendarWeeklyView" />
    ```
  - then, I am using this xml in my main activity as,

    ```
    public class TimeTableActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_timetable);
            super.onCreate(arg0);
        }

    }
    ```
- Here is calendar_weekly

  ```
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" >

          <RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/calendar_header"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="44dp"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:background="@android:color/white" >

              <TextView
                  android:id="@+id/currentWeekDateWithMonth"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:text="01/01 - 01/08" />
          </RelativeLayout>

          <GridView
              android:id="@+id/calendar_days_grid_weekly"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@id/calendar_header"
              android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
              android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
              android:numColumns="8"
              android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

          <ViewSwitcher
              android:id="@+id/calendar_switcher_weekly"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_below="@id/calendar_days_grid_weekly"
              android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

              <GridView
                  android:id="@+id/calendar_grid_weekly"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                  android:numColumns="8"
                  android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                  android:verticalSpacing="1dp" />
          </ViewSwitcher>

      </RelativeLayout>
  ```

here is the stacktrace...

```
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nyurals.school/com.nyurals.school.TimeTableActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at com.nyurals.school.TimeTableActivity.onCreate(TimeTableActivity.java:15)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     ... 11 more
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nyural.calendar.CalendarWeeklyView cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
09-26 08:04:32.820: E/AndroidRuntime(3038):     ... 21 more
```

why it is giving that exception????
please do reply asap as i am unable to resolve this issue....

Comment: please check it.. I have added stacktrace..

Comment: Using getActivity() is wrong . If we call getActivity() inside your fragment before onActivityCreated() get called. The we will get wrong reference

Comment: then... what is the solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass container `ViewGroup` object while you inflate the layout in `onCreateView` method of your fragment class. Hence in your case, try with

`calendarLayoutWeekly  = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.calender_weekly,container);`

**Edit** Try with exchanging `setContentView()` and `super.onCreate()` method. hence your code would be

`@Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {

          super.onCreate(arg0);

          setContentView(R.layout.activity_timetable);

    }`

Comment: @user2211108 : can you please post your activity_timetable.xml layout file please.

Comment: @user2211108 : Try the edited thing in my answer and let me know the result.

Comment: Hope you have given try by cleaning the project. Moreover, it would be good that you can post full activity_timetable.xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

This error is showing because of your calender_weekly xml file. Post your xml file here or check into your xml file, there is some issue.

Comment: Thanks... Here is calendar_weekly.xml

Comment: where is calender_weekly.xml?

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nyural.calendar.CalendarWeeklyView cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
```

Your `CalendarWeeklyView` is an `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, not `android.app.Fragment`. If you're on API level 11 or newer, just change the imports. If you're on older API level, your activity needs to extend the support library  `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`.

In either case, you cannot mix support library fragments and API 11+ fragments.